# Test and restart service with bash

Tags: bash

The goal of the script below is to test nginx configuration and if successful it will then restart the service as shown.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "checking nginx config..."
if sudo nginx -t | grep -q 'successful'; then
        echo "restaring nginx..."
        sudo systemctl restart nginx
fi
```

When this script is executed it prints

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

However, I wonder why the statement inside the if-statement does not run even if the result text contains "successful"

Comment: maybe the string is printed on stderr? And why do you check for the string, wouldn't it be simpler to just `if sudo nginx -t; then` ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
nginx -t
```

with

```
nginx -t 2>&1
```

to wirte its stderr to stdout.